# Am I on the right track with JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to learn how to develop jQuery plugins but have little guidance on the matter. I see lots of code on the web, of course, but am not sure what exactly constitutes best practices due to the level of variability in style.

- `$.notify` - Displays a simple notification bar similar to that of WP7's notification bar.
- `$.every` - Calls a callback/handler every n-seconds with an additional delay (used for timing animations)

```
(function ($) {
    $.notify = function (message, options) {
        var bodyElement = $('body');

        var controller = bodyElement.data('jscom.NotifyController');
        if(controller == undefined || controller == null){
            controller = new NotifyController(options);
            bodyElement.data('jscom.NotifyController', controller);
        }

        controller.notify(message, options);

        return controller;
    };

    function NotifyController(options){
        // Helper elements & variables
        var bodyElement = $('body');
        var scope = this;

        var notificationElement = bodyElement.find('#JSNotification');

        if(notificationElement == undefined || notificationElement.length <= 0){
            bodyElement.append('<div id="JSNotification"></div>');
            notificationElement = bodyElement.find('#JSNotification');
            notificationElement.html('<p></p><div class="progress"><!--progress--></div>');
        }       

        this.updateSettings(options);

        this.target = notificationElement;
        this.timer = null;
        this.timestamp = 0;

        this.target.hover(
            function() { $(this).addClass('mouse-over'); },
            function() { $(this).removeClass('mouse-over'); scope.onMouseOut(); }
        );

        this.target.every(1, 0, function(){
            scope.update();
        });
    };

    NotifyController.prototype.updateSettings = function(options){
        /* Setup the settings & options */
        var defaults = { timeout: 4000, cssClass: 'default' };
        var settings = $.extend(
            { }, 
            defaults, 
            options
        );

        this.timeout = settings.timeout;
        this.cssClass = settings.cssClass;
    };

    NotifyController.prototype.notify = function(message, options){
        if(this.timer != null){
            clearTimeout(this.timer);
            this.timer = null;
        }
        this.target.attr('class', '');
        this.updateSettings(options);

        var timestamp = new Date();

        this.target.find('p').html(
            '<span class="datestamp">' + 
            timestamp.format("h:MM:ss TT").toString() + 
            '</span><span class="message">' + 
            message + 
            '</span>'
        )
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.target.addClass('active').addClass(this.cssClass);


        var scope = this;
        this.timer = setTimeout(
            function() { scope.close(); }, 
            this.timeout
        );
    };

    NotifyController.prototype.update = function(){
        if(this.target.hasClass('mouse-over')){     
            this.timestamp = new Date();

            return;
        }

        var time = new Date();
        var delta = time - this.timestamp;

        var percent = (delta / this.timeout * 100).toFixed(0);
        if(percent > 100) percent = 100;

        this.target.find('.progress').css('width', percent.toString() + '%');
    };

    NotifyController.prototype.onMouseOut = function(){
        if(this.timer != undefined && this.timer != null){
            clearTimeout(this.timer);
            this.timer = null;
        }

        var scope = this;
        this.timer = setTimeout(
            function() { scope.close(); }, 
            this.timeout
        );

        this.timestamp = new Date();
    };

    NotifyController.prototype.close = function(){
        if(this.target.hasClass('mouse-over')){
            return;
        }

        this.target.removeClass('active'); //.removeClass(this.cssClass);
    };

    /* EVERY CONTROLLER */
    $.fn.every = function(interval, pauseInterval, callback, id){
        if(id == undefined || id == null) { id = ''; }

        var controller = this.data('jscom.EveryController-' + id);

        if(controller == undefined || controller == null){
            controller = new EveryController(this, interval, pauseInterval, callback);

            this.data('jscom.EveryController-' + id, controller);
        }

        controller.init();

        return controller;
    };

    function EveryController(element, interval, pauseInterval, callback){
        this.element = element;
        this.interval = interval;
        this.pauseInterval = pauseInterval;
        this.callback = callback;

        this.timerId = null;
    }

    EveryController.prototype.init = function(){
        this.reset();
    }

    EveryController.prototype.reset = function(){
        // Clear the timer
        clearTimeout(this.timerId);

        var scope = this;

        // Wait for a bit...
        this.timerId = setTimeout(function() { scope.timeOut(); }, this.interval);
    }

    EveryController.prototype.timeOut = function () {
        // Reset the timer and perform the callback
        clearTimeout(this.timerId);
        if (this.callback) {
            this.callback();
        }

        // Setup the delay (adjust for animation)
        var scope = this;
        this.timerId = setTimeout(function () { scope.reset(); }, this.pauseInterval);
    }

})(jQuery);
```

How to invoke:

```
$('#TestNotifyTimeoutColor').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.notify(
        '<a href="index.htm">hello, world!</a>',
        { timeout: 1000, cssClass: 'red' }                      
    );
});
```

Comment: C# techniques actually translate to js quite nicely if you are a big-time linq-over-collections user. Basically both languages support and encourage a partially functional paradigm.

Comment: Another minor note, $.notify and $.every are terms with a high probability of clashing with other plugins. You might want to prefix them or provide a no-conflict mode.

Comment: Is there any benefit to (what I would call) namespacing them? Such as $.js.notify?

Comment: The benefit is that you decrease the probability of conflicts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's see.

First of all by glancing on the code, you don't seem to know what `==` does.

Especially by looking at `this.timer != undefined && this.timer != null` this does the **exact same** check twice as *type coercion* is happening behind the scenes. Type coercion also makes `0 == '' // true`. You should [read up on it](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#types.equality).

No, concerning the style, I took the time to refactor your code a bit (while hopefully not introducing any errors :D )

```
(function ($) {

    $.notify = function(message, options) {

        var bodyElement = $('body'),
            controller = bodyElement.data('jscom.NotifyController');

        if (controller == null) { // using type coercion is fine, but only for a null and undefined check at the same time
            controller = new NotifyController(options);
            bodyElement.data('jscom.NotifyController', controller);
        }

        controller.notify(message, options);
        return controller;

    };

    function NotifyController(options) { // Whitespace before the {

        // Helper elements & variables
        var bodyElement = $('body'),
            that = this; // "scope" here well, most people use "that". There are some people that use "self", but keep in mind that there is a global variable called "self" that references the window object.

        var notificationElement = bodyElement.find('#JSNotification');

        if (notificationElement === undefined || notificationElement.length <= 0) {
            bodyElement.append('<div id="JSNotification"></div>');
            notificationElement = bodyElement.find('#JSNotification');
            notificationElement.html('<p></p><div class="progress"><!--progress--></div>');
        }

        this.updateSettings(options);

        this.target = notificationElement;
        this.timer = null;
        this.timestamp = 0;

        //  you should avoid putting stuff on the same line
        this.target.hover(function() {
                $(this).addClass('mouse-over');

            }, function() {
                $(this).removeClass('mouse-over');
                that.onMouseOut();
            }
        );

        this.target.every(1, 0, function() {
            that.update();
        });

    };

    // Doing NotifyController.prototype.updateSettings = .. is cumbersome and bloated, just assign the prototype object
    // The style below is a lot more readable
    NotifyController.prototype = {


        updateSettings: function(options) {
            /* Setup the settings & options */
            var defaults = { // again avoid stuff on the same line
                timeout: 4000,
                cssClass: 'default'
            };

            // no need here though
            var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            this.timeout = settings.timeout;
            this.cssClass = settings.cssClass;

        },

        notify: function(message, options){

            if (this.timer != null) {
                clearTimeout(this.timer);
                this.timer = null;
            }

            this.target.attr('class', '');
            this.updateSettings(options);

            var timestamp = new Date();

            this.target.find('p').html(
                '<span class="datestamp">' +
                timestamp.format("h:MM:ss TT").toString() +
                '</span><span class="message">' +
                message +
                '</span>'
            )

            this.timestamp = timestamp;
            this.target.addClass('active').addClass(this.cssClass);


            var that = this;
            this.timer = setTimeout(function() {
                that.close();

            }, this.timeout);

        },

        update: function() {

            if (this.target.hasClass('mouse-over')) {
                this.timestamp = new Date();
                return;
            }

            var time = new Date();
            var delta = time - this.timestamp;

            var percent = (delta / this.timeout * 100).toFixed(0);

            // Also stay away from shorthand ifs, not a good style to go with.
            if (percent > 100) {
                percent = 100;   
            }

            this.target.find('.progress').css('width', percent.toString() + '%');
        },

        onMouseOut: function() {

            if (this.timer != undefined && this.timer != null) {
                clearTimeout(this.timer);
                this.timer = null;
            }

            var that = this;
            this.timer = setTimeout(
                function() { that.close(); },
                this.timeout
            );

            this.timestamp = new Date();
        };

        close: function() {

            // Whitespace on ifs also helps readability
            // it also aligns the body with the condition :)
            if (this.target.hasClass('mouse-over')){
                return;
            }

            this.target.removeClass('active'); //.removeClass(this.cssClass);

        }

    }

    /* EVERY CONTROLLER */
    $.fn.every = function(interval, pauseInterval, callback, id) {

        if (id != null) {
            id = '';
        }

        var controller = this.data('jscom.EveryController-' + id);

        if (controller != null) {
            controller = new EveryController(this, interval, pauseInterval, callback);
            this.data('jscom.EveryController-' + id, controller);
        }

        controller.init();
        return controller;

    };

    function EveryController(element, interval, pauseInterval, callback) {

        this.element = element;
        this.interval = interval;
        this.pauseInterval = pauseInterval;
        this.callback = callback;
        this.timerId = null;

    }

    EveryController.prototype = {

        init: function() {
            this.reset();
        },

        reset: function() {

            // Clear the timer
            clearTimeout(this.timerId);

            var that = this;

            // Wait for a bit...
            this.timerId = setTimeout(function() {
                that.timeOut();

            }, this.interval);

        },

        timeOut: function () {

            // Reset the timer and perform the callback
            clearTimeout(this.timerId);
            if (this.callback) {
                this.callback();
            }

            // Setup the delay (adjust for animation)
            var that = this;
            this.timerId = setTimeout(function() {
                that.reset();

            }, this.pauseInterval);

        }

    }

})(jQuery);
```

Other than the stuff I've pointed out, I think it's quite good code ( I've seen a lot of horrible JavaScript from people who come from other languages and try to do some quick "jQueries" ).

I suggest that you dig into some of JavaScripts quirks a bit more. I already pulled the shameless plug with the [JavaScript-Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden) but you might consider checking out two great books on the topic:

- [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do) - Pretty much the "bible" of JS, you should have read it , but take the author Douglas Crockford with a grain of salt, he's a very opinionated man. You should definitely reflect on his thoughts though, there's a lot of wisdom in the book but you have to know how to use it.
- [JavaScript Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do) I consider this a great book, nothing in there I didn't know before, but I've been doing JS for years and this is a splendid compilation of common Patterns and Idioms and a great built up on top of Crockfords book. Also, if you only have the time to read one, I'd go with this, as it briefly covers some topics from *The Good Parts* in the beginning.

Crockford also did a lot of Video talks on JS just Google for his name with Video and they should pop up :)

Comment: Thank you for the help - I updated the code based on your suggestions. Are there any downsides to using the "NotifyController.prototype = { }" setup? (https://github.com/jsedlak/jsMetro/blob/1edcceeaf03c8d516dd1a00ee7c8a9f3934d407c/source/content/scripts/jscom.metro-tools.js)